# Prevent Chrome from reverting back deleted quick links

Tags: chrome-for-android

With the last update, I have some troubles with quick links icons on Chrome for Android. Every time I open a new tab or close and open Chrome, my quick links change with some of my earlier searches. I need to delete that new quick links every time and after deleting them, my old links are back.

Screenshot 1 is when some links are added automatically

[image]

Screenshot 2 is when deleting that search

[image]

Is it possible to fix that?